# C not operator why do I get a warning

Tags: c

Whats wrong with this code

```
typedef unsigned char datum; /* Set the data bus width to 8 bits. */

    datum pattern;
    datum antipattern;

    antipattern = ~pattern;


Remark[Pa091]: operator operates on value promoted to int (with possibly unexpected result) C:\filepath...\file.c 386
```

Compiler is IAR EWARM
why should two char variables need to be converted to an int. why should it complain about a change of sign when everything is declared as unsigned.

Any idea what cast to use to get rid of this warning?

Comment: try casting `~pattern`

Comment: `(datum) ~pattern` does not change the fact that `~` operates on an `int`. In theory, the implementation could take `pattern`, convert it to an `int`, invert all the bits, interpret the result as a one’s complement number, and convert that to `datum`. Then the result would be off by one from the desired result.

Comment: @DanielFischer Suppose I do like `antipattern = -pattern;` Would I get warning ?... because I am not getting warning

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That depends on the compiler and your desired warning level, I'd think. On most systems, `int` is wider than `char`, and two's complement, so it'll do the intended thing anyway. Then the compiler could see no reason to warn even with the highest warning level.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, right.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks Daniel got you point. EricPostpischil also [answered me for this I would like to share with you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838249/c-not-operator-why-do-i-get-a-warning/15838332#comment22535914_15838332)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules of C require that `unsigned char` operands be converted to `int` (except in perverse C implementations).

Once the operand is an `int`, it is signed, and the `~` operator may give you unexpected results, because the semantics for signed integers and their bit representations are not fully specified by C. The compiler is helpfully warning you about this.

You should use `antipattern = ~ (unsigned int) pattern;`. With `unsigned int`, you are guaranteed that the value is represented with simple binary.

Comment: Wow a response in 3 minutes. thaks guys. I knew this would cause some discussion, as its not always easy to find out standard C behaviour. antipattern = ~ (unsigned int) pattern; did indeed fix the problem.

Comment: Hi Eric! I have cross question: Suppose I do like `antipattern = -pattern;` (I am using minus) Would I get warning ?... because I am not getting warning

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: The `-` operator is doing arithmetic, and arithmetic is largely defined on integers; the `-` of 3 is -3, and the `-` of -2 is 2, for example. `~` is different because it operates on the bits of the representation of the value rather than on the value itself. C does not specify whether signed integers use one’s complement or two’s complement (although the latter is overwhelmingly used today), so we do not absolutely know what the bits of `-2` are, so the result of `~ -2` is questionable.

Comment: In other words, we know that the `-` of `-2` is 2, but we do not know what the `~` of the bits of `-2` is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil WaW Eric nice Understood and got-something new too. Nice explanation Thanks