# Why not use complement of VAL instead of (-VAL -1)

Tags: c

I'm reading redis' source code from https://github.com/antirez/redis.

I saw such macros in src/ziplist.c

```
#define INT24_MAX 0x7fffff

#define INT24_MIN (-INT24_MAX - 1)
```

why not just do this?

```
#define INT24_MIN (~INT24_MAX)
```

Comment: `~` will give you warning, that it may change sign `operator operates on value promoted to int (with possibly unexpected result)`

Comment: Read this [C not operator why do I get a warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838249/c-not-operator-why-do-i-get-a-warning) May be you find helpful

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning even though adding -Wall with gcc4.8. Is it compiler related?

Comment: Do you call your macro?? May be it need more option/flag ...btw It was my guess answer otherwise I might post in answer section :)

Comment: I call it and still no warnings. Thanks your comments anyway:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better question might be why do you think `(~INT24_MAX)`  is better than `(-INT24_MAX - 1)`?

On a two's complement machine you get the same result from either expression, and both of them evaluate just as fast as the other (for a 32-bit target, the compiler will reduce both of them them to `0xff800000` at compile time). However, in my opinion the expression `(-INT24_MAX - 1)` models the numeric concept that the minimum value is one less than the negation of the maximum value better.

That might not be of any huge importance, but the expression `(~INT24_MAX)` isn't better in an objective way, and I'd argue that subjectively it might not be as good.

Basically, `(-INT24_MAX - 1)` might have been what the coder happened to think of (maybe since as I mentioned, it models what's numerically intended), and there's no reason to use something else.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm thinking complement code when I first saw this and even be a bit confused of why it's named "MIN". Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Suppose, `int` is 32-bit and can hold `0x7fffff`, then `~0x7fffff` is going to be `~0x007fffff` or, after all bits have been inverted, `0xff800000`.

This bit pattern represents the negative value `-0x7fffff-1` if negative integers use the 2's complement representation.

If they use the 1's complement representation, then this pattern represents the negative value `-0x7fffff`.

If they use the sign-magnitude representation, then this pattern represents the negtative value `-0x7f800000`.

As you can see, the value of `~0x7fffff` is going to depend on the representation of negative integers and the size of the type that can hold the value `0x7fffff`.

If you're trying to write portable C code, you should avoid such situations.